# rails model association problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

im working on this model association class assignment. the basic association works, but im having issue with the "category"-page view.

Category Page Output should be (/categories/1)

- Dish-ID
- Dish-Title
- Restaurant-Title <= HOW DO I GET THIS VALUE?

rules:
- dish belongs to one category 
- same dish can be in multiple restaurants

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dishes
end

class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dishes
end

class DishRestaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :restaurants
  has_many  :dishes
end
```

Category Controller

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @dishes = @category.dishes
  // RESTAURANT TITLE ??

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @category }
end
```

Category View:
    <%= debug @dishes %>

any hint would be helpful.

thanks

pete

Answer (score 1):

Define you models properly:

```
class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_and_belongs_to_many :restaurants
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dishes
end
```

This would use the implicit join table names "dishes_restaurants". You only need a join model is you store some join specific information, like price of the dish in the restaurant. In which case you models should be like:

```
class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :dish_restaurants
  has_many :restaurants, through => :dish_restaurants
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dish_restaurants
  has_many :dishes, through => :dish_restaurants
end

class DishRestaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :restaurant
  belongs_to  :dish
end
```

Whatever approach you follow, you can do `dish.restaurants` to retrieve the list of the restaurants which serve the dish.